# Show widget for choosing members from user contact list in Telegram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I'm looking for a way to show the user a widget with a list of his contacts from which he can select several members (as happens when adding new members to a group).

I already looked for something similar in the Telegram documentation, but I could not find anything.

Does the Telegram API provide such an opportunity at all?

P.S.: I work with aiogram, but first I would like to know if this is even possible.

Comment: in telegram or in python code ?

Comment: The widget should be shown in telegram, but I want to call it from the Python code. I think that at least for this there should be a suitable method in the Telegram API.